# On publish getting multiple same requests pubnubv4 rails

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pubnub

I have a rails app that is API based using pub-nub v4. Same for client side(IOS/Android) using pub-nub.

Here are the steps we are doing:

1) On create any object we are subscribing two channel's and creating a listener.here.At same time on client end we are subscribing two channel's on basis of this object id.

2) So for any publish from IOS end for same channels creating multiple requests at web end.so multiple DB entries are going to create.

Here is the code sample of subscribing and unsubscribing.

```
$pubnub.add_listener("broadcast_#{broadcast.id.to_s}")

$pubnub.subscribe("broadcast_#{broadcast.id.to_s},broadcastLikes_#{broadcast.id.to_s}") 


$pubnub.publish("broadcast_#{self.id.to_s}", { type: "StopBroadcast", text: text })
$pubnub.remove_listener("broadcast_#{self.id.to_s}")
$pubnub.unsubscribe("broadcast_#{self.id.to_s}, broadcastLikes_#{self.id.to_s}")
```

Anyone can help me!

Comment: Why are you subscribing from your Rails server? If you need to send messages from your clients to your server, why not just POST them? All you are doing by subscribing from your server is replacing traditional web app POST which doesn't really provide any advantage. The part that you should be using PubNub for is the other direction: server to client.

Comment: @CraigConover What is the role of add_listener here?What is the relationship between subscribe and add_listener?Because without add_listener I am unable to track subscribed callback, so please let me know,it is urgent.

Comment: Please provide any example, how can we deal with multiple listeners whose name is generated dynamically.

Comment: The listener is for all channel subscribes responses and statuses. What is your requirement for multiple listeners?

Comment: Actually on every model object create, we are creating listeners with dynamic name and on destroy we are removing this listener by name.But after some requests we are getting multiple callback for same type.Here is scenario:

Comment: Right, with PubNub v4 SDKs, you create a single, global (app level) listener for all channels. What is it about your use case that requires individual listeners? I am not suggesting it isn't valid, just want to understand how single listener does not satisfy what individual listeners does.

Comment: @CraigConover We are creating single listener now because multiple listeners creating multiple entries at web end.But in case of single listener many times publish messages are missed at web end so I am not able to understand this scenario.Please let use know when we should remove this global level listener or should we remove? Please give your suggestion for same.

Comment: The listener can remain in place. When you subscribe to a channel, messages published to that channel will arrive in the listener. When you unsubscribe from a channel, you will no longer receive messages published to that channel. You can be subscribed to many channels so you can control which channels you are subscribed to (listening to) as desired. When you unsubscribe from all channels, you will not get anymore messages. If the individual listener (callback) design pattern is somehow more desirable, please let us know reasons (we are collecting feedback on this).

Comment: Actually we are embedding same callback to multiple listeners that we are creating.But I have a doubt is a single global listener able to handle multiple messages at same time,is there any chances to miss.Should we remove this listener or not?If yes then when?And as per new ruby pubnub v4 it is not showing more details about listener that's why getting confused.

Comment: The single listener design pattern will not miss any messages. There is no current support for multiple listeners (at least not out of the box) but that is why I am interested in the multiple listener requirement. But just know that the single/global listener will receive all messages published to all channels that your app is subscribed to.

Comment: And what about remove listener, should we need to do this?If yes then when.If no then there would be any problem.

Comment: As per multiple listeners requirement we can separate each listener with its own event listen so that would reduce load of single global listener .This in case multiple callback requests are hitting same callback at a time.

Comment: You don't need to to do `removeListener`, really. But if you no you are done with PubNub in the app, you can call it just to clean out a little bit of memory (very little though).

Comment: I assure you, you can use the single listener without any issues. It will not get overloaded :) The listener is multi-thread/thread-safe, otherwise PubNub would not work at all (or in a desirable way). I will probably take all these comments and create a final, official answer. Let me know if there are still any further things where you need clarity.

Comment: @CraigConover Thank you very much for your help.I am clear with all my doubts but in future if I would require then would ask you.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection of answers from the comments:

If you need to send messages from your clients to your server, why not just POST them? All you are doing by subscribing from your server is replacing traditional web app POST which doesn't really provide any advantage. The part that you should be using PubNub for is the other direction: server to client.

**Q:** *What is the role of add_listener here? What is the relationship between subscribe and add_listener?*

**A:** The listener is for all channel subscribes responses and statuses.
You only create a single, global (app level) listener for all channels. When you subscribe to a channel, messages published to that channel will arrive in the listener. When you unsubscribe from a channel, you will no longer receive messages published to that channel. You can be subscribed to many channels so you can control which channels you are subscribed to (listening to) as desired. When you unsubscribe from all channels, you will not get anymore messages.

**Q:** *I have a doubt is a single global listener able to handle multiple messages at same time,is there any chances to miss. Should we remove this listener or not? If yes then when? And as per new ruby PubNub v4 it is not showing more details about listener that's why getting confused.*

**A:** The single listener design pattern will not miss any messages. There is no current support for multiple listeners (at least not out of the box) but that is why I am interested in the multiple listener requirement. But just know that the single/global listener will receive all messages published to all channels that your app is subscribed to.

**Q:** *And what about remove listener, should we need to do this? If yes then when. If no then there would be any problem? As per multiple listeners requirement we can separate each listener with its own event listen so that would reduce load of single global listener. This in case multiple callback requests are hitting same callback at a time.*

**A:** You don't need to to do removeListener, really. But if you no you are done with PubNub in the app, you can call it just to clean out a little bit of memory (very little though). And I assure you, you can use the single listener without any issues. It will not get overloaded. The listener is multi-thread/thread-safe, otherwise PubNub would not work at all (or in a desirable way).